# JQuery check if it is dragging, if not then the dragged object returns to original position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drag-and-drop

I'm making an inventory system for a game, but I couldn't get dragging to work properly. I want to drag a div section, and when mouseup is detected, the div section goes back its original position. Problem occurs when I drag it on top of another div section, the mouseup event never triggered. It works properly when it is not on top of another div section.

Comment: Can you share your code by create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen for `mouseup` on document, like this:

```
$(document).on('mouseup', function(e){
     // do stuff here
});
```

The `mouseup` event bubbles up the DOM, so no matter on top of which element your mouse is it will bubble up to document, and that event listener will catch it (unless of course you have another listener in the middle which calls the `stopPropagation` method on the event object).

Comment: thanks man, this fixed everything, and its more efficient, before I was doing a mouseup and mousedown for every div in my inventory.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you looking for:

There is a `revert` function in [Jquery UI](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#rever)'s Draggable.

Answer (score 0):

Attach mousedown event to your div object but mousedown and mouseup events must be attached to the document object.